# How can I replace words that contain HTML tags without losing the HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, string-parsing

I'm working on a proper spellcheck dialog for the tinyMCE editor we are using in our application.

I'm at the step where I have all the word replacements determined and now I need to apply the changes to the innerHTML of the textarea.

My concern with this is being able to handle any markup that may be within a word. (Because users cannot be trusted)

For example if I wanted to replace a word like  "some**word**" I'm going to have to handle the <b> tag  `some<b>word</b>` in some fashion. Probably like so...

**some**word -> **myreplacement**
so**mewo**rd   -> myreplacement
some**word** -> myreplacement
**so*mewo***rd -> **myreplacement**

```
<b>some</b>word        -> <b>myreplacement</b>
so<b>mewo</b>rd        -> myreplacement
some<b>word</b>        -> myreplacement<b></b>
<b>so<i>mewo</b>rd</i> -> <b>myreplacement</b><i></i>
```

But I don't really care as long as it doesn't wipe out paragraph wide formatting.

Is building a parser my only option?

Comment: Yup, or some crazy regular expression.

Comment: @Diodeus: What kind of parser would one need to write for that? I don't get it.

Comment: Don't use regular expression on HTML.

Comment: @NiklasB. I don't quite have it working yet.

Comment: @Biff: Fair enough, no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use HTML Purifier for the heavy and important work.

Then, to get separated words, I would break the contents where there is white space.

After this, you may want to use a regular expression to grab the tags from beginning and ending of the string.

And then apply "strip_tags" function to remove remaining tags in the middle of the word.

Finally, you have the "naked" word to apply the word replacement. If no replacement is needed, you can easily stay with the original string. Otherwise...

Next, you can put back the beginning and ending tags.

If you want to put back the tags in the middle, you will have to grab them in the "strip_tags" phase (maybe using regex instead of strip_tags, or maybe comparing the strip_tags result with the original string, in that phase). You will need to position these tags after the replaced word or prior to it.

Joining the word pieces together is also another easy part.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something like the search/replace-plugin that is shipped with tinymce. Have a look at the source code of this small plugin and you will find out that you can use the search and replace functions of this plugin for your scenario too.